# C# Drawstring Letter Spacing

Tags: c#, system.drawing

Is is somehow possible to control letter spacing when using Graphics.DrawString? I cannot find any overload to DrawString or Font that would allow me to do so.

```
g.DrawString("MyString", 
             new Font("Courier", 44, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), 
             Brushes.Black, 
             new PointF(262, 638));
```

By letter spacing I mean the distance between letters. With spacing MyString could look like M y S t r i n g if I added enough space.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not supported out of the box.  You'll either have to draw each letter individually (hard to get that right) or insert spaces in the string yourself.  You can stretch the letters by using Graphics.ScaleTransform() but that looks fugly.

Comment: I was able to just draw out each letter individually.

Comment: +1. Though not nice to hear, I do appreciate when someone comes out and tells you that something is not supported.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you could use the GDI API function `SetTextCharacterExtra(HDC hdc, int nCharExtra)` ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145092(VS.85).aspx)):

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] 
public static extern int SetTextCharacterExtra( 
    IntPtr hdc,    // DC handle
    int nCharExtra // extra-space value 
); 

public void Draw(Graphics g) 
{ 
    IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc(); 
    SetTextCharacterExtra(hdc, 24); //set spacing between characters 
    g.ReleaseHdc(hdc); 

    e.Graphics.DrawString("str",this.Font,Brushes.Black,0,0); 
}
```

Comment: I know it's been answered a long time ago, but I can't seem to make it work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Me neither. I mean, the code compiles, but setting the extra space has no visual effect.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has 8 up-votes. It is nonsense. SetTextCharacterExtra() is an GDI API while Graphics.DrawString() is a GDI++ function which is not affected by GDI settings at all. But this works if you use Textrenderer.DrawText() instead of Graphics.DrawString().

Answer (score 2):

I really do believe that ExtTextOut will resolve your problem. You can use the lpDx parameter to add an array of inter-character distances. Here is the pertinent MSN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported, but as a hack, you could loop through all the letters in the string, and insert a blank space character between each one.  You can create a simple function for it as such:

**Edit - I re-did this in Visual Studio and tested - bugs are now removed.**

```
private string SpacedString(string myOldString)
{

            System.Text.StringBuilder newStringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder("");
            foreach (char c in myOldString.ToCharArray())
            {
                newStringBuilder.Append(c.ToString() + ' ');
            }

            string MyNewString = "";
            if (newStringBuilder.Length > 0)
            {
                // remember to trim off the last inserted space
                MyNewString = newStringBuilder.ToString().Substring(0, newStringBuilder.Length - 1);
            }
            // no else needed if the StringBuilder's length is <= 0... The resultant string would just be "", which is what it was intitialized to when declared.
            return MyNewString;
}
```

Then your line of code above would just be modified as :

```
          g.DrawString(SpacedString("MyString"), new Font("Courier", 44, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), Brushes.Black, new PointF(262, 638));
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I ended up being able to just draw out each character individually though.

Comment: No problem.  Yours is not a bad option, either.

Comment: How about ```s= string.Join(" ", s.ToArray());```

Comment: The One's comment is the right answer, short solution and perfectly working