# SetTextCharacterExtra function is not working with DrawText function for specific fonts/font size

Tags: c#, winapi, drawing, system.drawing, drawtext

I am printing texts using wingdi functions with setting character spacing by [SetTextCharacterExtra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-settextcharacterextra) function. I am using [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext?view=netcore-3.1) method to draw texts which uses wingdi functions internally. My problem is, character spacing is not working for some texts - I noticed that it does not work for bigger font sizes. I have also tried [DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) function directly instead of TextRenderer.DrawText but still no luck.

[image]

This is the output where character spacing is not applied to `Special` text. I have tried with different spacing(-2, -3, -4, -5) but no luck. I have changed font type as well but still the same output. If you notice character spacing is applied properly for other texts like `Huggies Infant Boy 96pk`, and `Was $32.00`, and others.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

UPDATE:
Here is the sample code to reproduce this issue:

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool DrawText(IntPtr hdc, string text, int length, ref RECT rect, int formats);

```
    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool ExtTextOut(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y, uint options, IntPtr lprect, StringBuilder lpString, uint c, IntPtr lpDx);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int SetTextCharacterExtra(IntPtr hdc, int nCharExtra);

    public const int ETO_OPAQUE = 0x0002;

    static void PrintByTextRenderer()
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(delegate (Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            var str = "Drawing Text with Avenir Black";
            var font = new Font("Avenir Black", 140, new FontStyle());          // Calibri
            var rect = new Rectangle(200, 20, 4000, 400);

            IntPtr hPrinterDC = e.Graphics.GetHdc();
            if (hPrinterDC != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var nCharExtra = -5;
                SetTextCharacterExtra(hPrinterDC, nCharExtra);

                RECT rc = new RECT(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);

                //// METHOD 1 - winapi fn : DrawText : Intercharacter Spacing not working
                //var flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.NoClipping;
                //DrawText(hPrinterDC, str, str.Length, ref rc, (int)flags);

                //// METHOD 2 - winapi fn : ExtTextOut : Intercharacter Spacing is working properly
                //ExtTextOut(hPrinterDC, rc.left, rc.top, ETO_OPAQUE, IntPtr.Zero, new StringBuilder(str), (uint)str.Length, IntPtr.Zero);

                e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hPrinterDC);

                //// METHOD 3 - TextRenderer.DrawText : Intercharacter Spacing not working
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, str, font, rect, Color.Black);
            }
        });
        pd.Print();
    }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9OcK.png) is my test result. You can find that character spacing is working. Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please find the sample code updated in the question. This is sample code where I printed the string using DrawText(winapi function), TextRenderer.DrawText and ExtTextOut(winapi) but intercharacter spacing is only working with ExtTextOut but not with other two. Please paste this code to .NET Console application and run.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem in c#. However, this method is valid in the C++ sample. I checked the code and I am not sure if this is related to dc, because I am not familiar with C#. Maybe waiting for someone familiar with C# to solve this problem is a good choice. Related : [C# Drawstring Letter Spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969143/c-sharp-drawstring-letter-spacing)